# How to make same array values as key pair in PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am fetching options from my database table using PHP PDO.

```
 public function fetch_custom_options($type){
    $sql = "SELECT option_id, option_name,option_value,type,position FROM ts_options WHERE type=:type";
    $stmt = $this->dbConnection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":type", $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $rows;
}
```

As you can see in the query, I have two columns like option_name and option_value in the same table.
I want to make each option_name as key and each option_value as value and store it in an array() like this -

```
public function fetch_custom_options($type){
    $sql = "SELECT option_id, option_name,option_value,type,position FROM ts_options WHERE type=:type";
    $stmt = $this->dbConnection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":type", $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $custom=array(); 
    foreach($rows as $row){ 
        $custom[] = array($row['option_name']=>$row['option_value']);
    }
    return $custom;
}
```

When I use `option_name` value to access custom array value then it gives me undefine -

```
$rows= $getFromPostClass->fetch_custom_options('ad');
foreach($rows as $row) 
{ 
    $header_index=$row['header_index'];
}
echo $header_index;
```

The `header_index` is an `option_name` which is stored in the second array as a key.

```
Notice: Undefined index: header_index in
```

I have many values in my table like -

```
option_name , option_value ,type 
header_index, 12344   ,  ad 
below_title , 348478   ,  ad 
below_content , 77676  ,  ad
```

I am not sure about it but I elaborate it.
I want store `option_name` value as key and `option_value` value as value in array using `foreach()` loop -
I would access array value with name and get value -
like -
echo $row['header_index'];
The option_value of the same row should be displayed.

Comment: Have you done any var_dump on `$rows` to see what it contains?

Comment: You are looping over an array with different keys (_header_index, header_title, below_content)_, but then accessing the same key (_header_index_) on each iteration.

Comment: Inside the foreach loop use this: `$custom[$row['option_name']] = $row['option_value'];` to have a key value array in `$custom`;

Comment: Thank you. It's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an associative array, not a 2-dimensional array.

```
public function fetch_custom_options($type){
    $sql = "SELECT option_id, option_name,option_value,type,position FROM ts_options WHERE type=:type";
    $stmt = $this->dbConnection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":type", $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $custom=array(); 
    foreach($rows as $row){ 
        $custom[$row['option_name']]=>$row['option_value']);
    }
    return $custom;
}

$options= $getFromPostClass->fetch_custom_options('ad');
$headers = $options['header_index'];
```